# To implement Git diff in Java

Tags: java

I have been asked in an Interview to implement the Diff of two-paragraph in Java in the format of Git as we could see by Git diff in the terminal.

This is what I tried to attempt

This is what I came up to, however wasn't able to attaint the exact format asked.

```
 public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String file_1 = "Hi,\n" +
                "This line dosent change \n"+
                "My name is Alpit \n"+
                "What about you \n"+
                "Nice to meet you \n"+
                "How about we meet at coffe \n";
        String file_2 =  "Hi,\n"+
                "This line dosent change \n"+
                "My name is Test\n" +
                "What is yout name \n"+
                "Hope you have a good day ";

        gitDiff(file_1, file_2);
    }

    private static void gitDiff(String source, String changed){

        String splitSource [] = source.split("\n");
        String splitChanged [] = changed.split("\n");

        int toCheck = splitChanged.length>splitSource.length ? splitSource.length:splitChanged.length;

        for(int i =0 ;i< toCheck;i++){
            if(splitSource[i].equals(splitChanged[i])){
               System.out.println(" "+splitSource[i]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("++ " + splitChanged[i]);
                System.out.println("-- " + splitSource[i]);
            }
        }
        if(splitSource.length<splitChanged.length) {
            for (int k = toCheck - 1; k < splitChanged.length; k++) {
                System.out.println("++ " + splitChanged[k]);

            }
        }
        else if(splitSource.length>splitChanged.length){
            for (int k = toCheck ; k < splitSource.length; k++) {
                System.out.println("-- " + splitSource[k]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me out ?
Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Do you need the exact semantics of `git diff`? You might want to use the concept of edit distance to find the minimum number of characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) that need to be changed (add/delete/edit). For this, you do not even need to specially treat newline characters.

Comment: Not exact, just the  + - part

Comment: @TSG new line character was fine for them